# How to parse AuthoritiyInformation from X509Certificate object

Tags: java, x509certificate, bouncycastle

I want to retrieve the OCSP information from a given `X509Certificate` object. Since I don't know how to parse this information I am asking this question here.

Here is what I got so far:

```
X509Certificate x509cert = ... //The Certificate
ASN1Primitive obj = ASN1Primitive.fromByteArray(x509cert
                            .getExtensionValue(Extension.authorityInfoAccess
                                    .getId()));
AuthorityInformationAccess aia = AuthorityInformationAccess.getInstance(obj);
```

an exception is thrown:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown object in getInstance: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEROctetString
```

How do I parse a `ASN1Primitive` into a valid `DEROctetString` to progress?

The value of the `ASN1Primitive` in the example is:

```
3032303006082b060105050730018624687474703a2f2f6f6373702e616368656c6f732e64653a383038302f6f6373702f65676b
```

and seems to me to be a valid value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can build a `DEROctetString` using `ASN1InputStream`

```
byte[] authInfoAccessExtensionValue = x509cert.getExtensionValue(X509Extension.authorityInfoAccess.getId());
ASN1InputStream ais1 = new ASN1InputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(authInfoAccessExtensionValue ));
DEROctetString oct = (DEROctetString) (ais1.readObject());
ASN1InputStream ais2 = new ASN1InputStream(oct.getOctets());
AuthorityInformationAccess authorityInformationAccess = AuthorityInformationAccess.getInstance(ais2.readObject());
```

Try this code to get the OCSP URI meta-data within a X509Certificate. The code is extracted from class [OnlineOCSPSource](https://github.com/arhs/sd-dss/blob/master/apps/dss/core/dss-service/src/main/java/eu/europa/ec/markt/dss/validation102853/ocsp/OnlineOCSPSource.java) of SD-DSS project (and slightly modified)

```
public String getAccessLocation(X509Certificate certificate) throws IOException {

    final ASN1ObjectIdentifier ocspAccessMethod = X509ObjectIdentifiers.ocspAccessMethod;
    final byte[] authInfoAccessExtensionValue = certificate.getExtensionValue(X509Extension.authorityInfoAccess.getId());
    if (null == authInfoAccessExtensionValue) {

        return null;
    }
    ASN1InputStream ais1 = null;
    ASN1InputStream ais2 = null;
    try {

        final ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(authInfoAccessExtensionValue);
        ais1 = new ASN1InputStream(bais);
        final DEROctetString oct = (DEROctetString) (ais1.readObject());
        ais2 = new ASN1InputStream(oct.getOctets());
        final AuthorityInformationAccess authorityInformationAccess = AuthorityInformationAccess.getInstance(ais2.readObject());

        final AccessDescription[] accessDescriptions = authorityInformationAccess.getAccessDescriptions();
        for (AccessDescription accessDescription : accessDescriptions) {

            final boolean correctAccessMethod = accessDescription.getAccessMethod().equals(ocspAccessMethod);
            if (!correctAccessMethod) {

                continue;
            }
            final GeneralName gn = accessDescription.getAccessLocation();
            if (gn.getTagNo() != GeneralName.uniformResourceIdentifier) {
                //Not a uniform resource identifier
                continue;
            }
            final DERIA5String str = (DERIA5String) ((DERTaggedObject) gn.toASN1Primitive()).getObject();
            final String accessLocation = str.getString();

            return accessLocation;
        }
        return null;

    } finally {
        ais1.close();
        ais2.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution

Answer (score 4):

In **Bouncy Castle 1.57**, there's no need to create the intermediary `ASN1Primitive`. You can get the extension just by using the `org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Extension` and `org.bouncycastle.x509.extension.X509ExtensionUtil` classes:

```
X509Certificate cert = // the certificate

// get Authority Information Access extension
byte[] extVal = cert.getExtensionValue(Extension.authorityInfoAccess.getId());
AuthorityInformationAccess aia = AuthorityInformationAccess.getInstance(X509ExtensionUtil.fromExtensionValue(extVal));
```

Then you can use the `aia` object:

```
AccessDescription[] descriptions = aia.getAccessDescriptions();
for (AccessDescription ad : descriptions) {
    // ...
}
```

---

You can do it in previous versions as well, but for version <= 1.47 I believe that `Extension` class doesn't exist and you should use `org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.X509Extension` instead (I think that `org.bouncycastle.x509.extension.X509ExtensionUtil` is the same).